# Export SQL Server .bak file to sharepoint link

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I have a database within SQL Server that I need to export (send) to a sharepoint link.

[image]

I have researched that I can export the .bak file using the Wizard within SQL. How would I specify that I wish to send the file to a sharepoint? I am not sure if this is the correct process. Any suggestion will be helpful.

This is what I am doing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The EXPORT function that you have highlighted is NOT a backup and will not produce the .bak file that you expect.

Look at the [BACKUP command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) and the option to backup to URL specifically.  Your SharePoint folder should have a URL path that you could use.